# counting Plagarism in PHP

Tags: php

Forgive me if this isn't a programming oriented question.

Lets say we have two sentences

> [1]=This is a test idea
> [2]=This is an experimental idea

If I jumble up `[1]`

> [1]= a This idea test is

Would this count as plagiarism? What sort of logic do I have to apply to detect plagiarism.
I'm not making a complexed plagiarism service, but a rather simple one what can catch obvious plagiarism.

My logic is somewhat like this

```
<?php

$str1= "This is a test idea.";
$str2= "This is an experimental idea.";

echo "$str1<br>$str2<br>";

$str1Array = explode(" ",$str1);
$str2Array = explode(" ",$str2);

if(count($str1Array) > count($str2Array))
$max=count($str1Array);
else
$max=count($str2Array);

$word_seq = array();
$word_seq_history = array();
$c=0;
$plag_count=0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $lev = levenshtein($str1Array[$i], $str2Array[$i]);    // check for an exact match

        if ($lev == 0) {
            $c+=1;//  (exact match)
            //echo "<br>$c";
            $word = $str1Array[$i];
            array_push($word_seq,$word);
        }
        else
        {
           if($lev != 0){
             
                  if($c>=2)
                    $plag_count+= count($word_seq);
             $current_seq = implode(" ", $word_seq);
             array_push($word_seq_history,$current_seq);
             echo $current_seq;
             $c=0;
             $word_seq= array();
           }
        }
}

echo "plag_count:";
echo $plag_count;
echo "max:";
echo $max;
echo "<br>" ;
echo ($plag_count/$max)*100;

?>
```

Output:

> String 1: "This is a test idea."
>
> String 2: "This is an experimental idea."
>
> Words_Same:2 max:5
>
> Plagiarism: 40%

Do I need to change it or is it fine the way it is?

Comment: That all depends on your needs, now doesn't it?  I suspect that you are going to need a far more advanced algorithm to use this in any meaningful way.  See https://turnitin.com.

Comment: Well yeah this was just a start. I'm curious to know the methods to detect plagiarism, so that I can translate that in my code.

Comment: Again, that is up for you to figure out.  There isn't a standard method... it depends on what you want to detect, and how you want to do it.  You won't find a `detect_plagiarism($doc_a, $doc_b)` function anywhere, any more than you would find a `read_my_mind()` function.

Comment: shucks. I've been looking for that read_my_mind() function. I don't think your 40% would make sense this way just because it has similar words doesn't mean anything. "I like chicken" and "I like murder" share 66% plagiarism according to your algorithm. You'll need to define your own rule set for sure. Just our suggestions may be that you should make it a bit more intelligent.

Comment: and before you say it - by intelligent I mean figure a logical, code oriented way to express your own concerns. Like - break each text into sentences, then compare each sentence in each text with each of the others, compare each sentences word similarities, then check the position of each common word. Maybe store a lexicon database for synonyms and compare the dissimilar words with known synonyms and see if they match, etc. Lexicon DB can be bought

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to detect plagiarism in a very basic way is to first calibrate my system: ie first do a lot of comparisons with files from which you're sure aren't plagiated

1) compare a bunch of files with each other, detect the plagiarism rate with your function. Get out the words that are the most comonly used (let's say drop your rate up to XX%, trial and error here), put this words in your database and give them a weight of 0. Do this again without this words up to (less than XX%) (with regular expressions you can filter this words) and give them a weight of 1. And so on... Until you reach a plagiarism rate of nearly zero.

2) calculate the 'new' percent by sum(weight of words in your db that appear in the text)/ (the total weight of all your words) (and give the words that do not already come up in your database a weight of 10) = your rate

3) test it with plagiated stuff, if not ok, change a few parameters (weights)

Comment: and I know lexicons like the one you're creating exist, but this is a free way to build a very basic one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method, if used to check longer passages, will show a high level of correlation just because of common words, especially articles, prepositions, "be" verbs, and other common/overused words.  If you're writing about a variety of subjects, be it code or Shakespeare, you're likely to run across a jargon sets that are common to many genuinely unique papers.  I think you may need to look at an alternate approach.  Have you done any research into plagiarism and its detection?